# Using MaxMind or run a local whois to get visitor country code by IP

Tags: ip, whois, visitor-pattern, maxmind

what is the best method to get visitors country code by IP between the 2 following methods:

1. Using [MaxMind geoip database here](http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php.old/README).
2. Run a local whois and grep for the word country like this

   ```
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Get users IP
   $country = exec("whois $ip  | grep -i country");
   $country = str_replace('country: ', '', $country);
   ```

I heard that running a local who is is only work in linux server, is this correct?

Comment: Do not use `exec()` from your program to go to the shell to run a whois query and even worse pipe it with grep. Use the appropriate libraries in your programming languages for `whois` or just open a TCP socket on port 43 and read RFC3912 on Whois Protocol Specification.